# Transfering Json data to C# list

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, api

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using pdrake.Models;

namespace pdrake.Controllers
{
    public class MovieApiController : Controller
    {
        private const string baseUrl = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=my_key";
        public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
        public async Task<AcceptedResult> GetMovies()
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            }
            Movies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movie>>(Json(baseUrl));
            return View(Movies);
        }
    }
}
```

I've been struggling all day trying to figure out how to transfer the Json from baseUrl to the list Movies which can be looped through with a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Looks like you're converting the raw url to json...?

Answer (score 0):

Change your using block to the following,

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(baseUrl);
    string data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return View(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movie>>(data));
}
```

This will call the baseUrl along with receiving the text / content from the response. once you have the data, you can deserialize that to your `List<Movie>` object and return it as a View.

Comment: I did that and got an error cannot convert system.threading.tasks.task<string> to string

Comment: Although `HttpClient` implements `IDisposable`, using it in a `using` block is (counter-intuitively) wrong. `HttpClient` instances should be long-lived. Search the web for an explanation

Comment: The code is missing an `await` on the call to `ReadAsStringAsync`. That's why you're getting the *cannot convert* error

Comment: Ok that worked but I still can't resolve the view

Comment: Ah, I see i missed that part. It's fixed in the answer